# how do i fix this FSM C++ syntax error C3867

Tags: c++, syntax-error, state-machine, fsm

so I'm new to c++ and trying to create a FSM for this RPG game but i get 1 syntax error :
`C3867 non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`  but when i use the '&' i get another `error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression` here's my codes:

```
Class CNPC
{
private : 
    State <CNPC>* CurrentState;
    State<CNPC>* PrevState;
public:
    void ChangeState(State <CNPC> * NewState)
    void revertToPrevState(); 
    void OnUpdate(Uint32 time, Uint32 deltaTime)
}
```

CNPC.cpp for the change state function

```
void CNPC::changeState(State<CNPC>* pnewState)
{

    assert(CurrentState && pnewState);

    PrevState = CurrentState;

    CurrentState->Exit(this);

    CurrentState = pnewState;

    CurrentState->Enter(this);

}
```

the states header file

```
class P_Attack : public State<CNPC>
{
public:
    static P_Attack* Instance();
    virtual void Enter(CNPC* npc);
    virtual void Exucute(CNPC* npc);
    virtual void Exit(CNPC* npc);
private:
    P_Attack() {};
};
```

cpp file

```
P_Attack* P_Attack::Instance() // the same layout in all of the states 
{
    static P_Attack* S;
    return S;
}

void P_Attack::Exucute(CNPC*npc)
{ 

    npc->Attacked();


    if(npc->GetHealth() <= 0)
    {
        npc->changeState(Die::Instance()->Enter); // this is where im getting the error
    }
```

im sure the answer is obvious but it continues to elude me , pretty sure im doing something very stupid

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is due to the fact that you are accidentally passing a bound member function reference as an argument to the changeState function.

When you pass `Die::Instance()->Enter` as an argument, you aren't passing the return of the `Enter` member function but rather attempting to pass the memory address of the `Enter` function itself. This explains the first error telling you to append `&` as the compiler believes you are actually wanting to pass a function reference.

The following issue is that the syntax for passing member functions by reference requires you to refer to their class name, followed by scope resolution `::` followed by the member function name, hence getting an error if you try to pass `&Die::Instance()->Enter` as you are not properly passing a member function since member functions belong to the class, not to an instance. So you receive an error saying the operation is illegal as you are attempting to pass a member function which is bound to an object as if it were unbound. Essentially what the compiler expects to see is `&state<CBNC>::Enter` because the `Enter` method is bound to your state class, but it sees you attempting to take the address of the `Enter` function as if it belonged to something else.

That all said, assuming that `Die::Instance()->Enter()` requires no arguments, appending `()` as I just showed should resolve *those* errors, but not the underlying issue. 
I say this because it appears that your `Instance()` member function is likely a factory which returns the state object you really want to pass. If that is in fact the case simply passing `Die::Instance()` should suffice since the returned object will then invoke `Enter` once inside of your changeState function, properly invoking `Enter` on your instance as expected. I say it won't solve the underlying issue as it appears that your `Enter()` functions return void, thus simply changing the syntax to the above would attempt to pass the return of `Die::Instance()->Enter()` which would be void as the last function to execute is `Enter()` causing another error to appear.